# getUserMedia fails with TrackStartError when allowing accessing to microphone

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, webrtc

I am using Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114 m

When I run my html page using IIS (e.g., localhost/test.html) and hit "Allow" to the `http://localhost/ wants to use your microphone` prompt, getUserMedia() fails with the following error:

**NavigatorUserMediaError {constraintName: "", message: "", name: "TrackStartError"}**

Code:

```
var constraints = {audio: true, video: false};
...
function successCallback(stream) {
...
}

function errorCallback(error){
  console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
}

navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: have you tried a different microphone and camera? It could be something to do with the drivers.

Comment: @bwtrent Could be.  I've tried reinstalling the driver for my microphone.  Windows reports the latest version is installed and the microphone is working correctly.

Comment: I know that there have been [similar issues](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360512) and it seems to be driver based.

Answer (score -3):

var mediaConstraints =
{
    'mandatory' : 
    {
        'OfferToReceiveAudio' : true,
        'OfferToReceiveVideo' : false
    }
};

declare this in your code before using constraints.

Comment: But the error occurs before createOffer(function(offer) { ... }, null, mediaConstraints); is called.

Comment: -1 This has nothing to do with getting the user media. You are suggesting modifying SDP constraints which have nothing to do with actually getting the user media.